# How to form all possible combination of given digits to form a n-digit number without repetition of digits?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, logic, permutation

## Question

Let say we have a list of given digits and n (to form n-digit number)

```py
digits = [0, 1, 2]
n = 3
```

> List `digit` can not contain duplicate values.

How we can form all possible n digit numbers without repetition of digits. `n` can be any positive integer and list `digits` can have any length and digits in it.

> If length of list `digits` is less then `n` then no valid numbers can be formed.

---

## Conditions on number

**Valid Numbers**

```py
[120, 102, 201, 210]
```

**Invalis Numbers**

```py
[012, 112, 221, 212, 121]
```

> 012 is invalid because it is equivalent to 12 which is not a 3-digit number

---

#### Here is what I tried

```py
def formNum(L):
    num = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                  
                if (i!=j and i != 0 and j!=k and i!=k):
                    num.append(int(f"{L[i]}{L[j]}{L[k]}"))
                      
    return num

print(formNum([0, 1, 2]))
```

#### Output

```py
[102, 120, 201, 210]
```

But my solution will only work for 3 digits number and is very difficult to expand and for large value of n it is very slow.

---

My question is not similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104420/14541164) as this question ask for all possible arrangements of given digits but mine ask for all possible arrangements of digit to form a number of n-digits (n is given)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Comment: Then filter out all that start with 0

Comment: What if `digits` contains two times the same number?

Comment: @Martheen but I need the number to be of given length(n)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco it will not, let me clear it in the question

Comment: The point of permutation is each source member is only used at most once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
from itertools import permutations

num = [int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in permutations(digits, n) if p[0] != 0]
```

The output for your example:

```
[102, 120, 201, 210]
```

Comment: `12` and `21` are not valid permutations because the question specifies that all returned values are n digits long.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools` library has functions for working with permutations. `itertools.permutations(digits, n)` will return all n-length permutations of elements of `digits`.

Additionally, no permutation should start with a 0. We can apply this condition to every element by iterating over the permutations and keeping only those that match the condition.

We also want to convert each permutation into an integer. We can do this in a similar way to your method by converting each digit to a string, concatenating them all with `"".join`, and then converting back to an integer.

Final solution:

```python3
import itertools

digits = [0, 1, 2]
n = 3

result = set()
for permutation in itertools.permutations(digits, n):
    if permutation[0] != 0:
        number = int("".join(map(str, permutation)))
        result.add(number)

print(result)
```

Comment: Are you sure this approach works? have you run it?

Comment: Thanks for calling me out. I had run the code, but I made a last-minute change after copying it over and broke it. It's now fixed.